# Pandas converting Column of Lists to Column of Text Data Pre-Processing

Tags: python, pandas, join, google-colaboratory

I have a data set that looks like this:

| sentiment | text |
| --- | --- |
| positive | ['chewy', 'what', 'dhepburn', 'said'] |
| neutral | ['chewy', 'plus', 'you', 've', 'added'] |

and I want to convert it to this:

| sentiment | text |
| --- | --- |
| positive | chewy what dhepburn said |
| neutral | chewy plus you ve added |

I basically want to convert the 'text' column, which is made up of lists, into a column of text.

I've done multiple versions of this code:

```
def joinr(words):
   return ','.join(words)

#df['text'] = df.apply(lambda row: joinr(row['text']), axis=1)
#df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([x]))
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(joinr)
```

and I keep getting something that resembles this:

| sentiment | text |
| --- | --- |
| positive | ['c h e w y', 'w h a t', 'd h e p b u r n', 's a i d'] |
| neutral | ['c h e w y', 'p l u s', 'y o u', 'v e', 'a d d e d'] |

This is apart of data pre-processing for a ML model. I'm working in Google Colab (similar to Juypter Notebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is the axis = 1 you don't need that

```
data = {
    'sentiment' : ['positive', 'neutral'],
    'text' : ["['chewy', 'what', 'dhepburn', 'said']", "['chewy', 'plus', 'you', 've', 'added']"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('[', '')).apply(lambda x : x.replace(']', '')).apply(lambda x : x.replace("'", ''))
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))
df['text'] = df['text'].agg(' '.join)
df
```

Comment: Similar to the solution above, it works in the example dataframe, but when I apply it to my dataframe, it creates spaces in between the letters and it's still in list format.

Comment: I wonder if its because your "list" is actually a string, I updated the code to address if the text column is actually a string pretending to be a list

Comment: This gives me a results that looks like ['c h e w y', 'w h a t', ....

Comment: Even from the Data code I gave you?

Comment: Let me actually double check..

Comment: Dang, sorry boss I’m not sure what the problem is. It works fine on my end =\

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
df['test'].str.join(' ')
```

Demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [['chewy', 'what', 'dhepburn', 'said']]})
df['test'].str.join(' ')
```

Output:

```
0    chewy what dhepburn said
Name: test, dtype: object
```

Based on the comment:

```
#Preparing data
string = """sentiment   text
positive    ['chewy', 'what', 'dhepburn', 'said']
neutral ['chewy', 'plus', 'you', 've', 'added']"""
data = [x.split('\t') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])

#Solution
df['text'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)).str.join(' ')
```

Also, you can use more simply:

```
df['text'].str.replace("\[|\]|'|,",'')
```

Output:

```
0    chewy what dhepburn said
1     chewy plus you ve added
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: That certainly works in the dataframe you built as an example, but when I apply it to my dataframe, it looks the same as before doing the join.

Comment: The reason is that your col type is string not real list. Refer to my answer again.

Comment: Please let me know if your problem solved or not.

Comment: It didn't yet. I'm still playing around and checking to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you send part of your data in excel or csv file, so I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Ok, just emailed to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string representation of a list you can use:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(literal_eval(x)))
```

If really you just want to remove the brackets and commas, use a regex:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('[\[\',\]]', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
  sentiment                      text
0  positive  chewy what dhepburn said
1   neutral   chewy plus you ve added
```